# Laravel 5.4 one to many relationship

Tags: laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have two tables in my model:
- Groups (id, name, category_id)
- Categories (id, name)

I would need to show in my view a list with every group name and its corresponding category. Could you please show me how to populate the Eloquent method and also what do I need in the view side?

This is what I have so far but of course is not working

-- GroupController

```
`       public function index()
{
    $groups = Category::find(1);

    return view('groups.groups',compact('groups'));
}
```

-- Group
    `public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }`

-- CategoryController

```
`       public function groups()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Group');
}`
```

-- Category

```
`       public function groups()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Group');
}`
```

-- view

`@foreach($groups as $group)
{{$group->category}}
{{$group->category->name}}
@endforeach`

thanks!!

Comment: Did you define the relations in the models? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yes I just edited the answer and added the relations in both Controllers

Comment: You should create the relations in the models, not the controllers.

Comment: Ok many thanks i already moved the method to the models :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my comments, what you want is the following:

Models + relations:

Group model

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Category model

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Group::class);
}
```

Then in your Group controller:

```
public function index()
{
    // consider using paginate() instead of get()
    // using with('category') to eagerload the category (1 extra query) instead of querying for the category in the views foreach loop.
    $groups = Group::with('category')->get();

    return view('groups.groups',compact('groups'));
}
```

And in your view you can now list the groups and their category:

```
@foreach ($groups as $group)
    {{-- Assuming group and category have a name and category is always set --}}
    {{ $group->name }} : {{ $group->category->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach would be using Eloquent's Eager Loading:
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations

```
Group::with('category')->get()
```

For example:

```
      # Loop through all groups
      foreach(Group::with('category')->get() as $group){
        #get group name
        print $group->name;

        #get all categories related to this group
        $categories =  $group->category;
        foreach ($categories as $category){
            print $category->name;
        }
        print "<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it.
In the GroupsController added this

```
´
    $groups = Group::with('category')->get();

    return view('groups.groups',compact('groups'));
```

´
and in the view: 
`@foreach($groups as $group)  {{$group->category->name}}`

thanks for your help